# linq query to parse my class

Tags: c#, linq

I need to parse my class for some purpose to come up with specific text string for each property.

```
 namespace MyNameSpace
    {
        [MyAttribute]
        public class MyClass
        {

            [MyPropertyAttribute(DefaultValue = "Default Value 1")]
            public static string MyProperty1
            {
                get { return "hello1"; }
            }

            [MyPropertyAttribute(DefaultValue = "Default Value 2")]
            public static string MyProperty2
            {
                get { return "hello2"; }
            }

        }
    }
```

Here is my linq query to parse the file where this class lives

```
var lines =
    from line in File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\someFile.txt")
        where line.Contains("public static string ")
    select line.Split(' ').Last();


    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
         Console.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\", ", line));
    }
```

I am trying to output the following but I don't know how to write the linq query for this.

```
{"MyProperty1", "Default Value 1"}
{"MyProperty2", "Default Value 2"}
```

Comment: Do you really have to parse the *source* of your class? Do you not have a compiled version?

Comment: yes Jon, I am in a situation where I need the desired output as text.

Comment: I wasn't talking about the *output* - I was talking about the *input*.

Comment: Regardless of the desired output format, wouldn't it be easier to use reflection on the class in question?

Comment: this is one time throw away code that I need to write.. I thought parsing as text would be easier.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions may be a simpler solution:

```
var str = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\someFile.txt");
var regex =
    @"\[MyPropertyAttribute\(DefaultValue = ""([^""]+)""\)\]" +
    @"\s+public static string ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(str, regex);

foreach (var match in matches.Cast<Match>()) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{{\"{0}\", \"{1}\"}}", 
        match.Groups[2].Value, match.Groups[1].Value));
}
```

Sample output:

```
{"MyProperty1", "Default Value 1"}
{"MyProperty2", "Default Value 2"}
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/D1AUBK

Comment: "unable to compile" is not an error message.  What problem did you have?  This is not stand-alone code, it needs at least to be in a method of some class.  Also, you need to import at least the libraries I've included in the demo code sample.  **EDIT**: I just tested by copy-pasting the demo code (unedited) into a new project in VS 2010, and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in typeof (MyClass).GetProperties()) {
    var myPropertyAttribute =
        propertyInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false).Where(attr => attr is MyPropertyAttribute).SingleOrDefault<MyPropertyAttribute>();
    if (myPropertyAttribute != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("{{\"{0}\",\"{1}\"}}", propertyInfo.Name, myPropertyAttribute.DefaultValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: does not compile in vs2020  The type or namespace name 'MyPropertyAttribute' could not be found

Comment: `MyPropertyAttribute` is the name of your attribute. You need to use a using statement to qualify the namespace that the attribute is defined in, and reference the project that contains it (if it is defined in a separate project).